# Prove that the canonical matrix for $T$ can be unitarily diagonalized.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose that $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ has the property that $T^*=-T$.

Prove that the canonical matrix for $T$ can be unitarily diagonalized.

---

I'm having difficulty seeing what to do with the canonical matrix piece of the statement I am asked to prove. 
I know that if $T$ is normal, then it's unitarily diagonalizable, and vice-versa. However, beyond that I'm not sure what my next move should be.

Anyone care to give me a push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $T$ is normal ${}$